# VB.net: is it possible to refer to form elements outside of the form class?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm currently writing my first non-trivial VB.net program (so I'm coming from a position of relative ignorance). This program takes data from a DB (according to user input fields) and draws various plots based on that data.

I've decided to break my code up into classes / files in the way I find most intuitive. The UI methods are in the form class (basically all event handlers responding to user input in the various controls), the DB stuff is in its own class and file and the methods used to draw plots on the form are likewise compartmentalised in their own class / file.

The problem I face is that the DB class refers to various elements of the form class. For example, one of the DB methods is used to populate a combobox in the form class. But it obviously can't do this as it doesn't have access.

So, my questions are as follows:

- is there anyway I can make the form controls accessible outside of the form class?
- if so, would it be considered a good practice?
- or would I be better off making separate shared variables "shadowing" the fields I need to access and keeping any methods modifying the content of fields (e.g. adding items to comboboxes) confined to the form class itself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a) yes b) no c) or create Methods which other actors invoke to allow the owning form do something to the controls/display etc.  d) Leave forms as a user input sandbox and locate most of the app logic in classes

Comment: If you have access to [PluralSight](http://www.pluralsight.com) there is an excellent series on there by Mark Heath, called Windows Forms Best Practices that covers these concepts (the section on Patterns for Maintainable Code covers these topics specifically). I just finished it and I learned a ton. It is in C#, but the concepts will apply to VB as well. PluralSight offers free trials if you don't have a current subscription to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can pass a control object accessible from other objects, you generally don't have to do that and I personally consider it an uncommon practice unless there is a compelling reason.This goes for options 1 and 3 in your question. You want to strive to separate data from GUI in every possible way. This is specially true if your application is divided across teams of people with different skills and/or if you want to scale/re-use your application components and/or you want to simplify maintenance.

You need to be aware of the concepts:

- Layers and Tiers (UI/DAL/BLL/DB, etc.) - See:
  [Layered Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee658109.aspx)
- DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) - This would answer how data can move between layers/tiers. Dot Net provides many data structures that allows you to do this, for example, Generic Lists, DataTables, DataSets, ArrayLists, XML, etc. - See:
  [Pros and Cons of DTOs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236638.aspx)
- Binding concepts - How controls are associated with data structures.

After you have gone briefly through the above, I assume that you will see that you should keep GUI stuff in the UI code base.

To specifically answer your part of the question on how to bind a Combo Box from database, please refer to [Populate Combo from DB](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/533960/howplustoplusmakepluscomboboxplusreadplusfromplusd), as an example.

There are plenty of references that discuss the above concepts. It is very important to attempt to get your architecture as correct as possible from the get go.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that it's very important to establish good coding habits early on. I've reworked my code accordingly. Thanks also to the other excellent answers.

Answer (score 2):

> For example, one of the DB methods is used to populate a combobox in the form class.

Don't do that. Change your DB method to just return a list of the items. Then have code in your form call the method in the DB and populate the combobox with the results.

Comment: Agreed, I prefer data helper classes that specifically do this. It keeps thing nice and tidy, great point!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the form controls accessible by changing their access modifier to `Public`.  Probably not the best practice to get into, but you can do it if you want.

You would probably be better off having your form fire an event handler, which then calls your DB class to get the data you need, then call another method within the form class to draw your plots.  In my opinion, if the only thing that those methods are doing is drawing on the form, then there is no reason to abstract them out to some other class.